# Tornado WebSockets non-blocking requests using threading. Am I doing it right?

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I am new to Python and the problem I'm trying to solve is to have an on-going websocket connection that can take in requests, wait some time while doing calcs, return results when ready while not blocking other requests that come from other users/clients/connections. I have achieved this and it works rather nicely but wanted to check if this is the right solution. In this particular snippet they key bit is actions performed upon open: I spin off another thread with sleep.

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import time
import json
from tornado import gen
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from tornado.options import define, options, parse_command_line

define("port", default=8888, type=int)

thread_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(2)

class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    # Make this an asynchronous coroutine
    @gen.coroutine
    def on_message_coroutine(self, message):
        self.write_message('Message:', message)

        def worker_A(websocket, x):
            time.sleep(1)
            print('TICK', x)
            pass
            return x

        print('scheduling and yielding')
        for x in range(0, 30):
            test = yield thread_pool.submit(worker_A, self, x)
            self.write_message(json.dumps(test))

        print('done yielding')

    def open(self, *args):
        print("New connection")
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(self.on_message_coroutine, 'New Msg')

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def on_message(self, message):
        print("New message {}".format(message))
        self.write_message("You sent me this, sending it back in upper: " + message.upper())

    def on_close(self):
            print("Connection closed")

app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/ws/', WebSocketHandler),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Output on front-end's console below. "New message" bit is when I click the buttons while websocket is continuously returning other output (TICKS):

```
app.component.ts:17 Response from websocket: 11
app.component.ts:17 Response from websocket: 12
app.component.ts:17 Response from websocket: 13
app.component.ts:17 Response from websocket: 14
app.component.ts:24 new message from client to websocket:  gotta be a string
app.component.ts:17 Response from websocket: You sent me this, sending it back in upper: "GOTTA BE A STRING"
app.component.ts:17 Response from websocket: 15
app.component.ts:17 Response from websocket: 16
app.component.ts:17 Response from websocket: 17
app.component.ts:24 new message from client to websocket:  gotta be a string
app.component.ts:17 Response from websocket: You sent me this, sending it back in upper: "GOTTA BE A STRING"
app.component.ts:17 Response from websocket: 18
app.component.ts:17 Response from websocket: 19
app.component.ts:17 Response from websocket: 20
app.component.ts:17 Response from websocket: 21
```

Comment: Looks good to me, but perhaps consider using `async/await` instead of `yield`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this looks fine to me. The key thing to remember is that in `worker_A` (the function you pass to `executor.submit()`, you must not call `write_message`. Instead, return a value and write it after `yield executor.submit()` has returned.

Comment: thanks. Actually, that was my problem before I found this solution, inside the generator it had no idea what self or even passed down websocket object was. It just somehow lost scope. would you know exactly why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what this other version of the code might have been doing. If you're having a different problem, please ask a new question with more details.